# Bind key to custom script in feh

Tags: feh

Is there a way in which I can bind a keypress to a custom script (say a bash script) in feh? From [the manual](http://man.finalrewind.org/1/feh/) I have found out through ~/.config/feh/keys I can reconfigure keys, but as far as I know the commands should be predefined feh commands. Is there a way around this?

Particularly, what I want to do is capture the filename, when I press a particular key, and then run more operations on this file (or just copy the filename somewhere, if need be). Any options to get this done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Use the](http://man.finalrewind.org/1/feh/#x4f5054494f4e53)

```
--actionN [flag]action
```

option. Where `N` can be 1 to 9. If flag is `;` then *feh* does not load next image after action is done. Optionally `-A` or `--action` for `0` key  which is also bound to `Enter`.

#### Example 1:

```
feh --action1 "echo %n" *.png
```

When you press `1` action will be executed, in this case simply echoing the file name. The action will be executed by /bin/sh. Check out [FORMAT SPECIFIERS](http://man.finalrewind.org/1/feh/#x464f524d4154x20x53504543494649455253) for other image information.

#### Example 2:

```
feh --action1 ";~/some_script $PWD/%F" *.png
```

When `1` is pressed the script `~/some_script` are called with argument of file name and path. As action is preceded by `;`, *feh* will not load next image on completion of command.

---

Optionally you can also unbind the number keys and bind the actions `action_0 ... action_1` to other keys.

Comment: Wow, really great you can do all this with feh... thanks!!

Comment: Is there a way to execute a script AND move to the next image?